# Why would VNC view on mac OSX hang after accepting password?

Tags: mac-osx, mac, vnc

I'm trying to VNC into a Mac OSX machine. I can ssh in fine. I am also running this VNC connection over an SSH tunnel, however it worked fine yesterday.

I'm trying

```
$ vncviewer 127.0.0.1::13458
```

and it connects and gives the following output.

```
Connected to RFB server, using protocol version 3.8
Performing standard VNC authentication
Password:
```

I enter the VNC password. However it just hangs there and nothing happens. This happens if I enter a known incorrect password and the correct password.

What could be causing this and how would I go about diagnosing this?

Comment: did you try restarting the vnc service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is my fault. I think I was confused about passwords, and was entering the wrong password. D'oh!

Answer (score 4):

I've had similar things happen when the ARD service went fubar and needed a restart.  It's fairly simple over SSH.

If you are using a different VNC server then this still applies.  Try killing the process and restarting it.

To restart the ARDAgent - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2370

Basically.

ssh into the box and run

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -restart -agent
```

Comment: Apple's VNC server is very finicky when using non-Apple VNC clients.  If you leave the session open too long, or you let it time out, you _will_ need to restart ARD.

Comment: I tried that put that didn't solve it.